# psconfig in 2019 eating all the memory after patching

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, patching, psconfig

I've the following environment
1 sharepoint 2019 single host (windows 2016, 4 cpu, 16 GB RAM)
after every patch installation running the recommendend psconfig

`PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install`

I've noticed that the psconfig.exe is occupying all the server memory during the step 7

Performing configuration task 7 of 8

and sometimes I had to repeat the process since is failing due to memory exahustion
[image]

the only thing differente for other farms (except for the versions) is the in the farm the AzureCP trusted claim provider is deployed.

Did anyone noticed the same?

thanks

Andrea

Comment: How large are your content databases?

Comment: 3 GB in totlal for the content DB, 10 gb for all databases

Comment: You'd need a tool like [PrefView](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview) to track this one down. Requires the process be running.

Answer (score 2):

Your farm meets the minimum hardware requirements,  16 GB Ram and you have to increase it according to the installed application services

Comment: i do agree but i do not expect the psconfig eating all the memory and these is a developer farm: at the moment psconfig.exe is occupying 12 GB all alone and growliyng steady . Something is wrong in the psconfig behaviour